# Code execution cannot proceed because libquickmail-0.dll was not found?

Tags: c, c++11, dll, linker-errors, lib

I was looking for a quick and easy way to automatically send a file to my gmail for debugging purposes on multiple remote machines. However I am apparently having linking issues which I can't seem to solve.

I downloaded the win64 zip file of [libquick](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/), IDE is CodeBlocks, compile target is x64 and running on 64-bit Windows 10.

There were 10 files that came in the zip folder, in lib/include/bin. They were

bin > `libquickmail-0.dll`, `libquickmaillight-0.dll`, `quickmaillight.exe`.

include > `quickmail.h`.

lib > `libquickmail.a`, `libquickmail.dll.a`, `libquickmail.la`, `libquickmaillight.a`, `libquickmaillight.dll.a`, `libquickmaillight.la`.

I linked to all of the `.a`/`.dll.a`/`.la` and `.dll` files and it still gives me this error: `Code execution cannot proceed because libquickmail-0.dll was not found`

I have no idea what the problem is and am very open to ideas. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you get this error when you tried running the generated executable file?

Comment: I linked to all of these files with their full path names. Ex: "C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\...". And I just tried running the exe in the debug folder and got the same problem.

Comment: @ateesdalejr Added `libquickmail-0.dll` to my project folder and it stopped giving me that error. Now its giving me an error for libcurl4.dll

Comment: Has TDM-GCC's bin directory been added to your path? Also, do you have libcurl installed?

Comment: I don't have its bin directory added to my path and after a long time I have not been able to download libcurl dll. I have no idea where it's located. Every zip file I've downloaded has not had it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either copy the `libquickmail-0.dll` to the same directory as your linked executable or add the libquickmail `bin` directory to your path. This will allow Windows to find the DLL to run the executable.