# Problems with .dll files in MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw

I am trying to configure a program with Cmake using MinGW, but there are messages saying that libmingwex-0.dll, libisl-15.dll and libiconv-2.dll are missing and reinstalling may solve the problem.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(cloud_viewer)
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Errors show in a box saying (translation from polish): 
**Code execution cannot proceed because file.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.**

I have all of those .dlls in C:\MinGW\bin but it still is not solved. I have reinstalled both MinGW and Cmake, and Nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without the code and exact error message your question is **too vague**, so we can only *guess what you are doing*. Please, add the **code** (`CMakeLists.txt`) and the **exact error message**. After copy-pasting these things into the question post, you may format them with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: Is this ok now?

Comment: Well, so this is an error during the program's **execution**, not an error during the *build*. The error means that  the directory, where you have these libraries, are not in the **runtime** search path. Googling for the error message could reveal many SO questions, like that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656393/code-execution-cannot-proceed-because-libquickmail-0-dll-was-not-found. While it is about another library, the simplest solution is the same - copy required `.dll` into the folder with your executable.

Comment: I added Mingw\bin to path and it helped. Thanks